# Why Jena is not returning declared RDFS properties?

Tags: jena, owl, rdfs, apache-jena

I use Jena's OntClass.listDeclaredProperies() functions. Even every class is supposed to have all RDFS properties (e.g. rdfs:comment), listDeclaredProperies never returns any of them. How they are associated with a class and how to get them?

**Update 1**

I just thought that all ontology classes have also automatically declared RDFS properties. In documentation of RDFS properties is written for comment property "The rdfs:domain of rdfs:comment is rdfs:Resource". Because ontology classes are also rdfs:Resource I thought it should have the rdfs:comment property automatically and I should get it (together with other RDFS properties) by calling listDeclaredProperies function (this function returns also properties of superclasses) Probably I'm missing something about RDFS properties...

**Example**

So when I call listDeclaredProperies at any class (anyClass.listDeclaredProperies()), I would like to get all RDFS properties listed together with its "normal" properties. Why it doesn't work? We can add value of RDFS properties to any class or individual (e.g. label, comment etc.) Thanks for explanation.

Comment: **Even every class is supposed to have all RDFS properties (e.g. rdfs:comment),** I'm not sure what you mean by this, and I'm pretty sure it doesn't make sense with regard what listDeclaredPropeties [claims to return](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntClass.html#listDeclaredProperties-boolean-): "The properties in the frame-like view of the class are determined by comparing the domain of properties in this class's OntModel with the class itself."

Comment: Perhaps [object property for a class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23371640/1281433) will help, or [Parsing schema.org ttl/owl file using Jena](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22797424/1281433) (the answer is related to listDeclaredProperties). Also see [For an OWL class A; Getting all properties that A is their domain](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27924868/1281433).

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Listing properties associated with a class?  Or getting a list of RDFS properties?

Comment: A complete, minimal example would help to understand the question.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I added the update. Thanks.

Comment: RDFS is not the same as OWL.  Even though "The rdfs:domain of rdfs:comment is rdfs:Resource", that only really matters if you're *using* rdfs:comment.  I can write a webpage that says "The rdfs:domain of ex:hasFoo is rdfs:Resource", but Jena wouldn't know about that either.  However, if you use an RDFS reasoner that includes RDFS axioms, you *might* get the results you're looking for, but not necessarily, because listDeclaredProperties doesn't claim to return every property which could "be consistent" with a class.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks for explanation. I was confused and now it's much more clear for me what Jena is about together with RDFS. If you write your comment as an answer, then I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841701/jena-listdeclaredproperties-semantics